# Centering input field, container is a must?

Tags: css, center

I am trying to center an Input field, however, it seems ignore the margin: 0 auto; setting.

A container is necessary to center it?  Or I did something wrong?

Here is my sample code, as you can see, the box is centered, but not the Input field.

http://jsfiddle.net/EXZJm/

Many thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `input` a block element - http://jsfiddle.net/EXZJm/2/

```
  input{
      margin: 0px auto; 
      width: 100px;
      display: block; /* this */
  }
```

Comment: ignore the text align center that is an old hack for web displayers(i refuse to call it a browser) like ie6 which did not correctly render elements. This answer is the correct answer. And yes inline block wont work!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add text-align:center to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

As input are inline-elements by default, you could use `text-align: center;` on the parent box and omit the margin on the input.